# Unable to get StartSSL trust chain to work

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I received a free SSL certificate from StartSSL which I installed on my server. It works fine on desktop browsers and such but as soon as I open the website on my phone it says "**NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**".

When I test my site on different SSL checkers they all say my trust chain is incomplete or my Intermediate certificates are missing.

My site runs on a HAProxy loadbalancer with two servers backend. I concatenated my certificate with the private key and placed it in the configuration of HAProxy, but I have no idea how to configure it so it also includes the Intermediate certificates.

Comment: when you downloaded the certs zip from startssl, which cert package did you use? The cert in the `NginxServer.zip` has the intermediates already bundled in; the other setups require you to manually combine them, or for situations where you don't need them chained.

Comment: @pete I see, I used the `OtherServer.zip`. I will try it with the `NginxServer.zip` and report back. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @pete Wow, this actually solved it. I concatenated the bundle from the `NginxServer.zip` with my private key and used that as SSL certificate in HAProxy and now it works. I can't thank you enough, you made my day! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**StartSSL** splits their certificate distributions into sub-packages for use with the common server setups - ***IIS***, ***Apache*** and ***Nginx*** - each simply contains the common naming scheme and appropriate intermediate certificate bundling.

The package `OtherServer.zip` has the individual certificates separated as individual files: the intermediate, *your* issued cert, and a root cert *(which you shouldn't need.)* If you have used this package, the *Intermediate Certificate* `1_Intermediate.crt` needs to be concatenated to *your* issued certificate to complete the chain.

The concatenation step has already been taken for the ***Nginx*** package, and using that would be the fastest solution.